# React Native fetch request is not displaying user's post properties

Tags: json, mongodb, react-native, fetch-api

Just a simple React Native fetch request to MongoDB database. I'm trying to display dynamic JSON properties for a user's post, for example postedBy, title, etc. But when I set something like title or description I get nothing at all, just blankness.

Post.js

```
const mongoose =  require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema.Types

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  postdesc: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  img: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }, 
  postedBy: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }
})



mongoose.model("Post", postSchema)
```

fetch api code

```
router.get('/allposts', requireLogin, (req, res)=>{
 
  Post.find()
  .populate('postedBy', '_id username')
  .then( posts =>{
    res.json({ posts })
  })
  .catch( err=>{
    console.log(err)
  })
 })
```

fetch code

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState([])
 
 
    useEffect(()=>{
        AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
        .then(async (data) => {
        fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/allposts', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(data).token
            }
        }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then( result=>{
            console.log(result)
            setData(result.posts)
        })
    })
    }, [])
```

return code

```
return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.c1}>
        
        
          {
            data.map(( item )=>{
                return(
                    <View key={item}>
                
                <Text style={styles.postedBy} >{ data.postedBy }</Text>
                <Text style={styles.title} >{ data.title }</Text>
                
                </View>
                )
            })
          }
          
          
        </View>  
      </View>
    )
  }
```

What I want is: The title of my post is "Here is a title from db".

What I'm getting is: The title of my post is [Blank space] .

Note: the `console.log(result)` is showing the post's json in console just fine.

```
LOG {"posts": [{"__v": 0, "title": "Here is a title"`...etc, etc }]}
```

Comment: Just a **typo**. You want `{item.postedBy}`, `{item.title}`, etc. `data` is your array whereas `item` represents each element within the array

Comment: when I run {item.postedBy}, {item.title} I get this error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, username}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: If `postedBy` is not a plain string, you need to pull the data out of it. Probably `{item.postedBy.username}`